# SQL query for displaying specific data

Tags: sql, reporting

I am trying to get the number of people who have specific code numbers.

Below is an example of what I am doing now.
`select * from persons where code in ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5')`

The `in` will show me everyone who has those numbers, but that doesn't exclude anything. I'm not sure how to show those that have ONLY those codes and nothing else.

Hopefully this makes some sense.

Comment: "but that doesn't exclude anything" Ummm...yes. Yes, it does. That query won't display any rows of `persons` having, for example, `code = '6'`.

Comment: Sorry, I realize it won't display any other rows but if I look up the people separately I can see other codes like '6', and I don't want those people showing up on the report at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that, you need to look at all the numbers.  The best way is using `group by` and `having`:

```
select personid
from person
group by personid
having sum(case when code not in ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5') then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

The `having` clause counts the number of records that are not those codes.  If the count is 0, then the record is returned.

If you want to be sure that all 5 codes are selected, then use this condition:

```
having sum(case when code not in ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5') then 1 else 0 end) = 0 and
       count(distinct code) = 5
```

Answer (score 0):

This is quick and dirty, and I'm assuming the presence of an ID field on the persons table...

```
select a.*
  from persons a
  join (select id,count(*) count
          from persons b
         where code in ('1','2','3','4','5')
         group by id
        having count()=1) b
    on a.id=b.b.id
```

**EDIT: Think I like this version slightly better :) **

The idea here is to get only those person records with exactly one ID from the list, hence the count. Join that back to the same persons table and it will list the only record having the value in the target list.